# Is there a limit on the size of a WP page?

Tags: plugins, limit

I have a plugin that generates a gallery of user photos. Currently, it works using `img` tags pointing to the user photo image. It attaches to the `the_content` filter.

I'm experimenting with converting to using data URLs. I'm able to generate them with no difficulty, but when I change the code to insert them into the page, requests *to* that page come back with zero content (i.e. zero length). However, I still get a 200 status code and I don't see any errors in my logs.

So, I'm wondering if WP has a limit on the size of page it will send. The data URLs add up to around 1MB, so I was wondering if that tripped it over some limit.

- [Gallery generation code](https://github.com/nerd-nite/nerd-nite-plugin/blob/master/nerd-gallery.php)
- [User Photo code](https://github.com/nerd-nite/user-photo/blob/master/src/user-photo.php)

Any suggestions?

The salient code is:

```
$file = trailingslashit($upload_dir['basedir']) . 'userphoto/' . $image_file;
$fileContents = base64_encode(file_get_contents($file));
error_log($fileContents);
$src = "data:image/jpg;base64,$fileContents";
...
...
$img .= '<img src="' . htmlspecialchars($src) . '"';
...
$img .= ' />';
```

In case it's relevant, the content is in a page not a post and it would go here: http://nerdnite.com/nerds/

So, that page, but with data URLs instead of image source files.

### EDIT

What I *do* now know is that it's not the generation of the content string by the filter. I can generate the string (which is of length 1229923), but if I pass a dummy string back, everything works well.

My memory usage is negligible and I'm nowhere near my PHP limit... so it seems to be something to do with WordPress trying to handle that huge string.

Comment: how do you generate a page? show your code

Comment: The code simply loops over all of the users and generates an `img` element. If I set the `src` attribute to the URL of the image, it works without any problems. If I switch to set the `src` to a data URL, I get a zero-length response. The only difference between the two is the code above.

Comment: I added links to the code. This is the version that is *working*. The snippet in the question comes from line 167  in user_photo.php

Comment: why don't you want to use URLs of images? it is better, because browser can cache your images and the page load time will be reduced.

Comment: I'm experimenting to determine which is better. Putting images in as data-urls means that when page is loaded it's done... no need to request any other assets. I'll be doing A/B testing to see which version my users prefer.

Comment: It's debatable as to whether the images should be cached, since my admins could change their user photo at any point in time, meaning that they are dynamic content.

Comment: Are you using a custom page template? If so, please post the custom page template code in its entirety.

Comment: @ChipBennett: How would the template affect things? All I'm doing is changing the content from one set of characters to another (larger) set of characters. Curious as to your hypothesis.

Comment: I have no hypothesis. We need to see *actual code*, to know what you're doing. You've given us a small, out-of-context bit of code that doesn't help us answer your question.

Comment: @ChipBennett I've included links in the question to two files that contain the code that's generating the output.

Answer (score 1):

Some of your user pictures are 30K characters long when encoded. Have you heard of URL length limit? See [What is the maximum length of a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/417184/577418).

Also I believe there are some limits were put by browser manufacturers in spite of HTML 4-5 specifications does not put any limits on attribute value length (AFAIK).

Comment: Why would that result in WordPress returning a zero-length response?

Comment: Possibly it has own limit too. 30K long URL does not seems to be legit.

Comment: Since I see this problem in FF, I don't think that's it. FF limit is unlimited (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs). *If* there's a WP limit, I'd love to know where it is.

Comment: May be you are right. I've found this answer: [Data protocol URL size limitations](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9957921/577418). When I'll get some time I'll dig into WP core to see if there are some trimmings or limitations. But remember, I'm not a guru, just my pleasure to help!

Comment: Firefox 19.0 on Ubuntu returns no HTTP headers. Just nothing. Chromium 24 on Ubuntu 12.04 says "(Failed)". See URI (not URL) lenght.